# NativeApplicationClient is not supported any

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

When using this code  In my Visual Stuidio Win form project.

```
var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, ClientId, ClientSecret);
```

I am getting a message

> NativeApplicationClient is not supported any more and it's going to be removed in 1.7.0-beta.  Consider using the new Google.Apis.Auth NuGet package which supports .NET 4, .NET for Windows Store apps, Windows Phone 7.5 and 8 and Portable Class Libraries as well

I am using

> install-package Google.Apis.Authentication -pre

If i add Google.apis.auth instead of Google.Apis.Authentication it doesnt apeare to even have NativeApplicationClient.  But I cant find any information on what I'm suposed to be using insted of NativeApplicationClient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes i got it working.

Install these packages in your project

```
pm> install-package google.apis -pre
pm> install-package google.apis.drive.v2 -pre
```

Add these usings

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System.Threading;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 UserCredential credential;
 using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open,
                                 FileAccess.Read))  {
    GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Tasks.Auth.Store";
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
            DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;
    }
```

}

For google drive i would then create a drive service. You send all the calls against the service.  Works the same for google analytics.

```
BaseClientService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
 HttpClientInitializer = credential,
 ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
 });
```

I expain it all in a blog post: http://daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/

If you figuer out how to feed it a stored refrshToken and use that let me know i'm still trying to figuer that out.

Comment: May i know what is the use of  GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Tasks.Auth.Store" ?

Comment: if you remove filedatastore   GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder  will tell it where to store the authentication. you technically don't need both.

Comment: Here is a newer tutorial that explains it better then this http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/